# How to wire a Hunter Remote Ceiling Fan (Exeter) and utilize both wall switches

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I want to install a Hunter Exeter fan. The fan is remote operated for both lights and fan speed, however, I have two switches on the wall - one for the fan and one for the light.

I would like one of the switches to turn on the light, and the other to provide power for the fan (which I can then use the remote to control).

[Here are the installation instructions](https://a.sellpoint.net/a/Exeter+English+owner%27s+manual.pdf.pdf?spworld_assetname=rYB7lXeG.pdf&spworld_download=1&spworld_filename=Exeter%20English%20owner%27s%20manual.pdf.pdf)

**Diagram 1: This is my 'hack' attempted at it. Left switch goes directly to the light, the right one powers the fan.**

[image]

**Diagram 2: Below this is the version the manual says. I'm not sure which functions the yellow and blue wires from the receiver, so I'm taking a guess in Diagram #1. I don't like this one because the right switch is a dud after you've wired it.**

[image]

****Update 8/15
I finally got around to wiring the fan, and the experts here on stackoverflow were right. The blue wire from the fan goes directly to the black wire from the ceiling to turn on the light directly from the switch. And yellow wire from the reciever connects directly to the black wire on the fan. Both switches work! I capped off the blue wire from the receiver.**

Important Note: You might need to wire it per the manual first to make sure the light on the fan is turned on from the remote. The fan remembers the last setting and when powered goes back to that setting.**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a functioning link to the manual for your fan? (Hunter's website is horribly broken :/)

Comment: Verify that the blue wire is for the fan. Blue is usually for the light fixture.

Comment: Assuming blue wire is for the fan, does the diagram look feasible? It’s either blue or yellow, but part of me wonders if it will short circuit the receiver if i do it wrong. https://a.sellpoint.net/a/Exeter+English+owner%27s+manual.pdf.pdf?spworld_assetname=rYB7lXeG.pdf&spworld_download=1&spworld_filename=Exeter%20English%20owner%27s%20manual.pdf.pdf

Comment: @michaelw -- how deadset are you on using the receiver that came with the fan?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the remote is the only way to adjust the speed on the fan (no fan chains), so if I direct connect the wire, we will have no control over the speed.

Comment: @michaelw -- I'm asking because oftentimes, the fan remotes that come with fans are horribly inflexible, leaving you better off with something else for a fan controller

Comment: Is the power from the two wall switches be controlled by dimmer switches? Or wall switches on or off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be fine. The receiver shouldn't care or be hurt if the light kit isn't connected to it (it's the exact same situation, electrically, as not installing light bulbs or having the bulbs burned out).

Be sure to cover the light wire from the receiver securely - put one of the supplied wire nuts on it tightly, then secure with electrical tape so it doesn't fall off.

If it's not clear from the instructions which wire on the fan is for the motor and which is for the light, you could try powering each (one at a time) and the white with a cord and plug before you hang the fan. Do it before you install the blades and you won't have to worry about hitting anything if you happen to find the fan wire first.

Comment: A) if you're concerned that the wire nut is going to fall off either the nut is too big or it's not screwed on tight enough. A tug on the wire & nut should not separate them. B) Every fan I've ever installed (from different manufacturers) has always been a "blue light" special. i.e. the blue internal wiring is for the lights while black or red is for the fan.

Comment: Agree that tape should never be needed for a properly-done wire nut on multiple wires (especially solid), but getting one to stay on a single stranded wire is a bit iffy.

Comment: You _did_ get my up vote, I made the comment more for anyone reading the answer than for you.